JavaFX overlay app initialisation and threading not behaving as expected
I have created a JavaFX application that needs to run as an overlay. Because of different requirements we're starting it with Platform.startup(). The first stage that I create is a splash screen like so (pseudo-Kotlin follows):
class SplashScreen : Stage(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT) {
    init {
        isAlwaysOnTop = true

        // create root, configure, etc.

        val scene = Scene(root, w, h)
        scene.fill = Color.TRANSPARENT

        this.scene = scene
    }
}

fun main() {

    System.setProperty("apple.awt.UIElement", "true") // https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/lsuielement
    Platform.setImplicitExit(false) // Due to app requirements
    Platform.startup {
        instance = SplashScreen().apply { show() }
    }
}

The problem with that code is that JavaFX seems to be ignoring the "apple.awt.UIElement" property, and creates a menu and adds it to the application switch pane in macOS.
On the other hand, if I call Platform.startup() inside a new thread it picks up the property without any issue and starts as required.
fun main() {

    System.setProperty("apple.awt.UIElement", "true") // https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/lsuielement
    Thread {
        Platform.setImplicitExit(false) // Due to app requirements
        Platform.startup {
            instance = SplashScreen().apply { show() }
        }
    }.start()
}

Why is this behaving that way? I would expect that the property should be picked up by JavaFX right after defining it.

The API documentation says, somewhat unhelpfully, "Changing a standard system property may have unpredictable results unless otherwise specified. Property values may be cached during initialization or on first use. Setting a standard property after initialization using ... setProperty(String, String) ... may not have the desired effect."

Following on from @James_D comment, did you try setting the [System] property in the java command - using the -D option, i.e. -Dapple.awt.UIElement=true

The documentation says to define properties in your bundle's information property list, and that "the system needs to know a few things about your app’s user interface before execution begins".

In the Mac application's Info.plist, try setting the StartOnMainThread key to true.

@James_D this makes sense and aligns with the results that I'm observing, which are quite inconsistent. In this specific case we needed a somehow dynamic configuration, but I am considering other options to be able to have the system property defined in the command line as @Abra suggested, and also including LSUIElement in Info.plist for good mesure as @jewelsea points out. Thanks all, will update the question after trying it out.

@trashgod could you point me to some documentation? I don't seem to find anything on Apple developer site.

@XavierRubioJansana: I recall it being required for SWT, for example. Any luck?

@trashgod -Dapple.awt.UIElement=true and adding LSUIElement made the trick, thanks. About StartOnMainThread, I see it's not needed in my case as I'm not getting the same crashes as in the example that you shared, but thanks for pointing it out.

You can answer your own question.
